# Parse Platform with Wordpress Authentication

Tags: wordpress, parse-platform

Im building an app which will be based around an already existing wordpress website.

the website already has quite a lot of users so we will be using the WP API to authenticate users based off the WP DB users table.

Every other action on the app will be done using a mongo DB so I just need to switch the authentication in parse to using the wordpress API. Has anyone come across a similar setup or any tips on swapping Parse Authentication for WP auth ?

Comment: it is not a common use case for Parse Server and I'm not sure you will able to do this with the current feature set. I think your best chance is by trying to use a https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforelogin-trigger to validate the user credentials into WP database, then copy these credentials to Parse Server so it can validates as well. You can also request/open a PR for this feature at Parse Server Github repo.

Comment: Another suggestion (probably the best way) would be be writing a custom authentication adapter: http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#custom-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into it as well, and it seems the best option is to create a [**custom auth module** in Parse Server](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#custom-authentication-module)

There is [a guy on Github](https://github.com/enriquecerda/parse-server-wordpress-login) that seems to have made some progress with it. You could give it a try.